# After inject Identity get 404 error inside 401 in actions have [authorize] atterbute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-5

I want to use JWT authentication.
after adding Identity with below code get 404 error in witch action have [Authorize] attribute.

```
 services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and config Jwt Authentication with this code

```
        var secretkey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("vdvdavavadvadvadvdvadvavadvavadvavdav");
        var encryptionkey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("vdavebbaawsbbbrw");

        var TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretkey),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            TokenDecryptionKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(encryptionkey),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            ValidateTokenReplay = true
        };
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = TokenValidationParameters;

        });
```

Comment: Hi @alirezasejdei, if you use Identity for authorization, it will redirect to `Identity/Account/Login.cshtml` to login. Please check if the 404 url is `Identity/Account/Login`.

Comment: My problem was 404 error. because i using jwt auth. and set defult to berear and the identity must return 401 error. i fix this problem by using identity.ui packege and inect AddDefultsIdentity method inside AddIdentity.